# how to check if two string makes a third string recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

here is the problem we are given three strings.

```
a=partyrock
b=anthem
c=partyrockanthem
```

task is to check if string a and b combine can make string c. rule is that you cannot change the order if the letters in the string, but you can jump from one string to another. 
so lets says `c = pantartyrohemck` in this case you move from one string to another string to make final string.

here is my code for recursion the problem is that i cannot find a way to return the values. if you have easier way to do this please let me know thanks in advance.

```
public class Hw4c {
    public static boolean everyDayImShuffling(String a, String b, String c)
    {
        boolean result = shufflinga(a,b,c,0,0,0); 

             return result; 

    }
    public static boolean shufflinga (String a, String b, String c, int d, int e, int f)
    {
        if(a.substring(d,d+1).equals(c.substring(f,f+1)))
        {
            if(d!=a.length()-1)
            {
                d=d+1; 
                f=f+1; 
                shufflinga(a,b,c,d,e,f); 
            }
            else
            {
                if(e!=b.length()-1)
                shufflingb(a,b,c,d,e,f);
            }

        }
        else
        {
             shufflingb(a,b,c,d,e,f);
        }

       return true; 
    }
    public static boolean shufflingb (String a, String b, String c, int d, int e, int f)
    {

        if(b.substring(e,e+1).equals(c.substring(f,f+1)))
        {
            if(e!=b.length()-1)
            {   
                e=e+1;
                f=f+1; 
                shufflingb(a,b,c,d,e,f); 
            }
            else 
            {
                if(d!=a.length()-1)
                {
                    shufflinga(a,b,c,d,e,f); 
                }

            }
        }

        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it's cheating to ask others for a solution you've been challenged to solve?

Comment: i am just asking how should i approach it.

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot find a way to return the values"?  (Seems to me you return "true" with no effort.) (Methods can have a return type other than boolean.)

Comment: i am having going back and forth from my helping methods shuffling a and shufflingb. and than return the final answer

Comment: Like I said, you can have a return type other than boolean.  And null can be returned to indicate a "failure".

Answer (score 3):

I will try to design a solution in abstract

```
checkWords(String a, String b, String combined){

int _a = 0, _b = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < combined.length(); i++){
    char c = combined.charAt(i);  
    if (c == a.charAt(_a))
        _a++;
    else if (c == b.charAt(_b))
        _b++;
    else return false;
}

return true;
}
```

**Note this does not include checking for null or empty input strings**
**It neither does the decision whenever current a and b chars are equal**

Comment: @dflkjfhlkjhlkdsjf I have said, it does not cover this case, it's up to you to solve this.

Comment: ok thanks figured it out. only needed to put the condition when they both equal

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if ((a + b).equals(c)) {
  // Equals!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, dynamic statement to do it.

```
if((a + b).equals(c)) System.out.println("Equal");
```

Here is a method to accomplish the same thing:

```
public boolean recursiveEqual(String a, String b, String c) {
if((a + b).equals(c)) return true;
else return false;
}
```

Comment: the answer should be recursive

Comment: How does my answer not do that?